# How to call golang function in dialog from JS script

Tags: go, sciter

I am trying to build a UI using GO and Sciter JS
When button is clicked on the Sciter UI need to call a function in GO. Please help as I did not find any documentation on this.

Regards,
SK

Comment: Did you check this example? https://github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter/tree/master/examples/callback

Comment: Thank you it worked. https://sciter.com/forums/topic/how-to-call-golang-function-sciterjs/#post-77127